# adding images and links feature on a joomla 1.6 template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a custom template built for Joomla 1.6 and my client is using it on Joomla 2.5, this should generally work, but the issue is that it lacks the "images and links" capabilities that exist in the article settings. When I select an image it doesnt show on the site. I have been trying to figure out exactly how and where to edit in the template to make this work but all in vain. Please can you give me a procedure to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a com_content override, start by moving the folder /templates/your_template/html/com_content out of the way and see if they show up: if so, you can either

- update the com_content overrides you just moved, (look at the /components/com_content/views subfolders for samples of how it's done in core J2.5)
- live with the core 2.5 (maybe just work with styles)
- restart the override, to do so just copy the appropriate /components/com_content/views subfolders under /templates/your_template/html/com_content

beware of the naming pattern differences: http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides see the section "Copying or Creating Layout Files"